# Loop with await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

I want to run the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/getTransaction', (req,res) => {
  let transaction = getTransaction(req.body.id);

  let logs = getEncodedLogs(transaction.logs);
  console.log('SEND'); // Gets called before getEncodedLogs() returns Array
  return res.send(Object.assign(transaction, { logs }));
});

async function getEncodedLogs(logs) {
  let logsDecoded = [];
  await Promise.all(logs.map(async (log) => {
    logsDecoded.push({
      logIndex: log.logIndex,
      data: log.data,
      topics: log.topics
    });
  }));
  console.log(logsDecoded);
  return logsDecoded;
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
```

The issue I'm having is that `res.send(Object.assign(transaction, { logs }));` gets run before `getEncodedLogs()` has returned the processed `Array`. I could rewrite it to `let logs = await getEncodedLogs(transaction.logs);` but that would block the process. Is there a better way?

Comment: the `async` function `getEncodedLogs` returns a promise ... so you either `await` or use `logs.then` to wait for the promise returned by `getEncodedLogs` to resolve

Comment: and no ... waiting for a promise to resolve does not `block the process`

Comment: @JaromandaX there are other issues as well.   Like the logsDecoded.push in getEncodedLogs isnt async,  but it has async and Promise.all

Comment: oh, yes, there are other issues - this is why async/await is such a bad idea - it gives some people the false sense that their asynchronous code has transformed into synchronous code - that could somehow "block the process"

Comment: _"I'm new to ES7 and want to run the following code"_ ES7 doesn't support async/await. ES2017 will. Why is this function async: `async (log) => {`? _"Gets called before getEncodedLogs() returns Array"_ `getEncodedLogs` returns a promise. _"but that would block the process."__ Which process will be blocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So currently nothing in this example is actually async or needs to involve a Promise.   getTransactions might but without seeing the implementation I can't tell.  So therefore the answer could be represented like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/getTransaction', (req,res) => {
  let transaction = getTransaction(req.body.id);

  let logs = getEncodedLogs(transaction.logs);
  console.log('SEND'); // Gets called before getEncodedLogs() returns Array
  return res.send(Object.assign(transaction, { logs }));
});

function getEncodedLogs(logs) {
  return logs.map((log) => {
    return {
      logIndex: log.logIndex,
      data: log.data,
      topics: log.topics
    };
  }));
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
```

If we dive deeper and look at the following part of the question

```
let logsDecoded = [];
await Promise.all(logs.map(async (log) => {
  logsDecoded.push({
    logIndex: log.logIndex,
    data: log.data,
    topics: log.topics
  });
}));
```

logDecoded is just a normal array and therefore the async function within map is actually not async.

Answer (score 2):

`getEncodedLogs(transaction.logs)` doesn't return your logs, it returns a Promise that *resolves* to your logs when it has finished<sup>1</sup>. The simplest way of getting this to work as expected would be to add a `.then` callback:

```
app.post('/getTransaction', (req, res) => {
    let transaction = getTransaction(req.body.id);

    getEncodedLogs(transaction.logs).then(logs => {
        console.log('SEND');
        res.send(Object.assign(transaction, { logs }));
    });
});
```

---

<sup>1. as all `async` functions do - the `await` syntax is just a convenient way of saying 'wait for this promise to finish before you carry on executing this function, please'</sup>

Comment: + just for a footnote